# Temperature conversion confusion

Tags: temperature

I'm attempting to change -10 degrees C to K.

I'm looking at 2 formulas ,

Equation - $T(K) = T(C) + 273.15$

Conversions -

change in K = change in C

Obviously , i have to use the equation one . But my point is , I actually got confuse on which one to use . And what are their actual difference ? Difference between the conversions and equations . because according to the math itself , I should be able to use both ? Thanks !

Comment: Question unclear. What do you actually want to do - convert $-10°C$ to Kelvin scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change in temperature means variation of temperature. 
If the initial temperature is $T_{1}=10\ \text{K}$ and the final temperature is $T_{2}=20\ \text{K}$, then:
$$\Delta T=T_{2}-T_{1}=10\ \text{K}$$
Using the equation that you wrote, we can do the same thing in Celsius scale.
$$10\ \text{K}=-263.15^{\circ}\ \text{C}$$
$$20\ \text{K}=-253.15^{\circ}\ \text{C}$$

$$\Delta t=t_{2}-t_{1}=10^{\circ}\ \text{C}$$

A change in temperature with $10\ \text{K}$ is equal to a change in temperature with $10^{\circ}\ \text{C}$.